# Operator Like, field type timestamp, and Cyrillic? MySQL Bug?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, internationalization, pdo

Seems like MySQL Bug;
Request:

```
        SELECT  *
        FROM table
        WHERE (
        id LIKE          '%тест 199%' 
        OR `user` LIKE     '%тест 199%' 
        OR `user_datetime` LIKE '%тест 199%' 
        OR `user_comments` LIKE '%тест 199%' )
        ORDER BY id desc
        LIMIT 0, 10
```

**[Err] 1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like'**

And when we use latinic.
Request:

```
        SELECT  *
        FROM table
        WHERE (
        id LIKE          '%test 199%' 
        OR `user` LIKE     '%test 199%' 
        OR `user_datetime` LIKE '%test 199%' 
        OR `user_comments` LIKE '%test 199%' )
        ORDER BY id desc
        LIMIT 0, 10
```

**Request Success;**

How to deal with it?

All of my request are generated automatically, i cant change logic coz function generator has many dependence.

**Settings:**

```
SET NAMES utf8
Character set utf8 -- UTF-8 Unicode
Collation utf8_general_ci
```

**UPD** for @eggyal

```
Request: 
SHOW CREATE TABLE `comments`
Response:
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_datetime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_comments` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `user_comments` (`user_comments`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=128456 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

MySQL Version 5.5.10

Comment: With what characterset/collation are those columns stored?

Comment: @eggyal Character set utf8 -- UTF-8 Unicode
Collation utf8_general_ci

Comment: For **each and every** of those four columns?

Comment: @eggyal yeap, and this bug work only if in request one of field has type timestamp.

Comment: Can you show that in your question (i.e. the syntax of the same query working when the `TIMESTAMP` field is included)?  Also, can you show the output of ``SHOW CREATE TABLE `table` ``?

Comment: `user_datetime LIKE '%test 199%'` does not make any sense at all. There will **never** be a timestamp value that matches that value (let alone using `LIKE` on date/timestamp is highly questionable in the first place even if the value was something like a real date)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its part of search, he must search in all fields, coz 'test 199' only sample data. it can be anything, date, time, name, part of comment.Think wider.

Comment: @Darius: still, searching *anything* in a timestamp column does not make sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Try not to go beyond my question, if the query is constructed in this manner then the fact there are serious reasons.

Comment: @Darius: fair enough, but I would question the "serious reasons" to carry out a search that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
Request can be anything, text like("username"), date like("2012-04-18"), time like("12:02:52").
Its a Search. Do you understand? 
And this Search, work perfect on latinic data, but so happened that i need to search Cyrillic words, and i can't change logic, for filter non datetime in request, and i can't change request and extract timestamp fields as i say all of requests are generated automatically. Is it clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of MySQL are you using?  As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html):

> As of MySQL 5.5.3, implicit conversion of a numeric or temporal value to string produces a value that has a character set and collation determined by the [`character_set_connection`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_connection) and [`collation_connection`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_connection) system variables. (These variables commonly are set with [`SET NAMES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-statement.html). For information about connection character sets, see [Section 10.1.4, “Connection Character Sets and Collations”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html).)
>
> This change means that such a conversion results in a character (nonbinary) string (a [`CHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html), [`VARCHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html), or [`LONGTEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html) value), except when the connection character set is set to `binary`. In that case, the conversion result is a binary string (a [`BINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-varbinary.html), [`VARBINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-varbinary.html), or [`LONGBLOB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html) value).
>
> Before MySQL 5.5.3, an implicit conversion always produced a binary string, regardless of the connection character set. Such implicit conversions to string typically occur for functions that are passed numeric or temporal values when string values are more usual, and thus could have effects beyond the type of the converted value.

Therefore the implicit conversion of your `TIMESTAMP` column to a string that occurs when using the `LIKE` operator will *always* result in a string of the `binary` character set if you are using a version of MySQL earlier than 5.5.3 irrespective of `SET NAMES` (curiously this is also the case on sqlfiddle, which claims to be 5.5.20); since such strings cannot be compared with strings in the `utf8` character set, you must explicitly convert your `user_datetime` column to a UTF-8 string:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     `comments`
WHERE (
         `id`                                LIKE '%тест 199%' 
     OR  `user`                              LIKE '%тест 199%' 
     OR  CONVERT(`user_datetime` USING utf8) LIKE '%тест 199%' 
     OR  `user_comments`                     LIKE '%тест 199%'
)
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT    0, 10
```

Comment: What you think, should we send this bug to MySQL dev's?

Comment: @Darius: See my updated answer above.  I'm not sure why sqlfiddle always uses `binary` given that it claims to be 5.5.20, but I doubt it's a MySQL bug.  It might be something weird specific to them.  Perhaps someone else can shine some light?  What version are you using?

Comment: @eggyal - I'm trying to determine if there is some bug with sqlfiddle that I need to fix.  Take a look at this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a654d/5 I see that your query runs fine, but OP's original query throws the error that he mentions.  I assure you, the MySQL db that I'm running there is 5.5.20.  There is a chance that the db init script I am using might not be setting the encoding properly, though (assuming there really is a problem on my end).  Any tips about things you think should be different, I'd love to hear.  Thanks!

Comment: @JakeFeasel: I didn't mean to suggest for one second that I doubted sqlfiddle was indeed 5.5.20; but I don't have another install of that version to compare against... perhaps it is a bug with MySQL after all?  What do you get from using the mysql command line tool (with SET NAMES 'utf8')?

Comment: @eggyal - that's a good idea - I'll check the command line and let you know what I find. Thanks

Comment: @eggyal http://pastebin.com/XFxh1gUz - looks like the same thing from the command line.

Comment: @JakeFeasel: And one presumes [`CHARSET(user_datetime)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_charset) returns `binary`?  In which case, it appears to me to be contrary to the manual: I'd suggest filing a bug report.